# How to get form data in dynamic form in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have created dynamic form, here I want to send form data to controller. How can do this?

```
Here is plunker code link https://plnkr.co/edit/xmxDJHTPfJoSFwa2FWCB?p=preview
```

Issues:

1. when I change the value then element label also change.
2. How can I get the form data in product_submit function of controller.

All response appreciated.

Comment: For answer to your 1 you use the same variable as label name and as input value that's why there's the same value

Comment: Yes I know that but here I want form data with same name in controller because names are dynamic so I want values in Controller with same name.

Comment: Can I get these values in controller in new array with same name index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To solve label issues, in your html, I changed ng-model expression to bound into `getColumn.Value`
2. In controller, I can read value entered in `scope.getColumn[i].Value`

I also updated code https://plnkr.co/edit/KlhAb69seMzHsLuhqweR?p=preview

Comment: This array already present in controller. I can get that. but Here I need to get edited value associated with variable name

Comment: Because you use getColumn.Field for your ng-model. I update my answer and code. Pls look at it again.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<input type="text" 
       id="module_module" 
       ng-model="getCol.value" 
       required="required" 
       class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" 
       placeholder="Enter {{getCol.Field}}"
```

/>

Look here **`ng-model="getCol.value"`**. You are using filed name as text field model value. Filed name and value are different. That is what you want I suppose.

You can access the values easily from your controller as **`$scope.getColumn[1].value`**. Change index or iterate accordingly.

Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/IoVRW5M8LNU25txJKk1Z?p=preview)

Comment: But How can I get value in controller with associated variable name?

Comment: In your controller it is already on your `getColumn` array. This array holds objects. Each object has a `value`, just like your `Field` property. You can iterate over the array or directly access with index as `$scope.getColumn[1].value`.

Comment: I am getting error, please help me to change in plunker what you said.